# ASP.Net Menu Control - Horizontal - Not Showing Sub Options

Tags: asp.net, menuitem

I am trying to use the ASP:Menu control.  It is rather simple.  I want it Horizontal.  Each of those first level items will have Sub items.  I can get it Horizontal and when I hover over the **Instant Reports** or the **Configurable Reports** choice it seems to pop down a div or something but it is empty.  I have tried formatting and everything I can think of as well as find on the internet.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<asp:Menu ID="mnuChoices" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" DataSourceID="dsSiteMap">
</asp:Menu>
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="dsSiteMap" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
```

Here is the sitemap file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0">
<siteMapNode url="" title="MenuItems" description="">
    <siteMapNode url="" title="Instant Reports" description="">
        <siteMapNode url="" title="Current System Health" description="">
            <siteMapNode url="~/ConfigurableReports/PropCredit30/TestLog.aspx" title="TEST" description=""></siteMapNode>
        </siteMapNode>
        <siteMapNode url="" title="Credit on Renewal" description="" />
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="" title="Configurable Reports" description="">
        <siteMapNode url="~/ConfigurableReports/PropCredit30/AuditLog.aspx" title="Prop Credit 3 - Audit Log" description="" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/ConfigurableReports/PropCredit30/ErrorLog.aspx" title="Prop Credit 3 - Failure Log" description="" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMapNode>
```

This seems so easy.  What am I missing?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a problem I had with Menu, but that only occurred in IE8... IE8 handled the z-index wrong. Simple to fix luckily:

```
<asp:Menu ID="mnuChoices" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" 
            DataSourceID="dsSiteMap">
    <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="submenu" />
</asp:Menu>
```

css:

```
.submenu {z-index: 9999; /* IE8 FIX for asp:Menu */}
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed main menu like that: #NavigationMenu ul {z-index: 9999;}

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/03/23/asp-menu-fix-for-ie8-problem-available.aspx

cheers

Comment: This is correct.  However, I will set the following one as the "answer" simply because it was less reading.  :)

Comment: no problem..it is important that the problem is now solved ;) cheers