# ASP menu is not showing

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, menuitem

My web application menu isn't showing in any browser I use to test.

I looked around and checked out if it wasn't the z-index bug mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882319/asp-net-menu-control-horizontal-not-showing-sub-options), that seems to have caused some trouble to many people.
I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" Orientation="Horizontal" />
</asp:Menu>
```

I've got this as my SiteMap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode title="Pagina">
    <siteMapNode url="Default.aspx" title="Home" description="Página Inicial" />
    <siteMapNode url="Generos.aspx" title="Géneros" description="Géneros"  />
    <siteMapNode url="Artistas.aspx" title="Artistas" description="Artistas" />
    <siteMapNode url="Musicas.aspx" title="Musicas" description="Músicas" />
    <siteMapNode title="Admin" roles="Administrador">
      <siteMapNode url="Admin/Musicas.aspx" title="Musicas"/>
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Any suggestions about what might be wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a detailed how to on sitemap http://aspalliance.com/695.

Your scenario is quite simple.. and it should work. are you sure you haven't specified any other default SiteMapProvider in web.config?

Comment: Yup, I'm sure. I just checked, I have only one SiteMapProvider in web.config. All I've done was according to that how to. I even tried to create a new project to use as spike solution, using the same SiteMap and the same menu configuration. It worked in the spike project, but still, not in the main one. It will show the menu in the design mode in VisualStudio, but when I run it on debug, it just won't show in the site, not even in the source code from the page.

Comment: turns out you were kind of right :) I deleted the SiteMapProvider from the web.config, and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help you, you are using local page so that you should give(~/) is must.

```
url="~/Default.aspx"..
url="~/Generos.aspx"..
url="~/Artistas.aspx"..
```

.
now it show menu.

Comment: I'm sorry, that didn't make it.