# asp:menu insist being vertical (c# asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, menuitem

i added an asp:menu to my web application and added the property : Orientation="Horizontal"
The menu insist on being vertical in Explorer 8 on windows server 2008 R2.

it works ok in Firefox on the same server or 
in explorer 8 on a different computer with win 7.

how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by disabling the "Enhanced Security Configuration" on the Windows server 2008 - IE8.

Go to Control Panel-->Programs-->Turn windows features on or off--> usnder security information choose "Configure IE ESC" and set administrators and users to Off.

Doing this solved my Menu problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be a CSS issue. In IE8 hit F12 and inspect the CSS that is present. Are you using conditional comments to include IE only style sheets?

Comment: thanks forthe quick answer, i have no conditional comments and the menu stays vertical even if i don't include any CSS class on the menu.

Comment: ASP.NET generates the menu CSS on the fly, and it should be at the bottom on the page header. Is it the same if you put IE8 into IE7 or compatibility mode? There is a known issue with IE8 and the asp.net menu control, but I don't think it would cause this issue. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882319/asp-net-menu-control-horizontal-not-showing-sub-options

Comment: Solved it by disabling the "Enhanced Security Configuration" on the Windows server 2008 - IE8.

Go to Control Panel-->Programs-->Turn windows features on or off--> usnder security information choose "Configure IE ESC" and set administrators and users to Off.

Doing this solved my Menu problems.