# Sitemap's sub-menu are hidden behind a JavaScript image Gallery in Asp.net page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, image-gallery

In my asp.net page with sitemap menus and sub-menu is added a java-scripting and jQuery image gallery, but when I go for submenu it is hidden behind the image gallery.

My menu's css code are:

```
.menuItem
{     
    border:Outset 1px black;
    background-color:Gray;
    font:14px Arial;
    color:White;
    padding:8px;            
}
```

Menu and SiteMap:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1"  StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="menuItem"
        DynamicMenuItemStyle-CssClass="menuItem" Runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" DataSourceID="srcSiteMap" /> 
                                <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="srcSiteMap" Runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
```

Comment: Formatted your code so it shows up. Please do that in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net Menu Control - Horizontal - Not Showing Sub Options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882319/asp-net-menu-control-horizontal-not-showing-sub-options)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can fix that with setting both elements

```
position:relative; //or
position:absolute;
```

and then giving one element some lower number of

```
z-index: 0;
```

and other one some high number like

```
z-index: 10;
```

hope it helps.